# Objective-C ARC was enabled in PCH file but is currently disabled - Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to convert my Objective-C Project to ARC. Once I add the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag to one or more individual files in Build Phases, my `MyProject-Prefix.pch` file shows the following error:

> Objective-C automated reference counting was enabled in PCH file but is currently disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that :

- Compiler is set to Apple LLVM compiler 4.x
- Project property : `CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC` is enabled (change it to YES)
- You have cleaned your project (`Product -> clean`)

Following the steps above you will ensure that you have switched to ARC using the LLVM/clang compiler, if none of the above will solve the problem you can try disabling precompiled prefix unchecking Precompile Prefix Header (`GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER`) in XCode Build phases. The use of the PCH is not mandatory since is used to increase compilation time.

Comment: where can i choose this option ? can you give me a path or image ?